# assigning large string to textview.settext hangs UI

Tags: textview, android

I'm trying to show very large text (of length 850879) in textview, unfortunately when I  assign text to textview, UI hangs for 8-15 seconds! How do we fix this issue? any idea?

Comment: How big is `very large`? Do you have an example?

Comment: `850879` chars? That is a lot to be displayed on a mobile device screen..

Comment: so do we have any work around to fix it without blocking UI?

Comment: Yes, cut the text to a reasonable size and load the rest only if the user actually wants to read it

Answer (score 2):

Use Webview....instead of textview. Textview is not design to load large text.

```
WebView webView;
String html;
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you spilt the text in small chunks and provide it to a list view...  That way ui will not be blocked for what's not visible